# Renaming amazon s3 files using curl, recommendations?

Tags: amazon-s3, curl

## Renaming amazon s3 files using curl, recommendations?

I did review past threads for this situation. I did not get any threads, We have a situation. There is data upload process drop files into AWS S3. It will be in following forms.

- [Bucket]/[folder]/[file]
- [Bucket]/[folder1]/[file1]
- [Bucket]/[folder2]/[file3]

For example, I could have:

- MyBucket/supplier/profiles
- MyBucket/customer/profilec
- MyBucket/product/profilep

I want to add timestamp (rename) to above file like from on-prem linux

- MyBucket/supplier/profiles.202309231410
- MyBucket/customer/profilec.202308211120
- MyBucket/product/profilep.202307111555

We are not allowed to use AWS CLI (it will do this easily)

We are thinking of using a curl script to do above.

I see many scripts to upload files to s3 using curl like

```
curl -X PUT -T /path/to/local/file.jpg \
  -H "x-amz-acl: public-read" \
  -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" \
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/your-bucket-name/file.jpg" \
  -H "Authorization: AWS ACCESS_KEY_ID:SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
```

I did not find any such thing for renaming existing objects in s3.

Are we able to use curl in this situation?

Are there other better approaches without using AWS CLI?

Thank for your guidance.